# How contravarient metric tensor equals the cofactor of covarient metric tensor over its determinant?

Tags: metric-tensor, linear-algebra

[Is the contravariant form of the metric tensor the inverse of the covariant form of the metric tensor?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSaVu.png)

Comment: Hint: [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule).

Comment: The quick answer is yes: $g^{a\mu} g_{\mu b} = \delta^a_b$. For proof see any intro to general relativity.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax instead](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).